# How to make animation out of canvas images in Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, frame, kineticjs

I have the following code that is supposed to be three frames of an animation, how can I turn them into an animation in Kinetic.js? It's a hex like pacman, that opens and closes its mouth. 
I have three canvas images, as three frames, is there any built in function in Kinetic.js to do this? or should I create one from scratch? after I made the sprite, how can I do other animations like move it around, or rotate it, without breaking the animation(the pacman should still open and close its mouth)?

```
        pacMan1 = new Kinetic.Shape({
            x: 15,
            y: 13,
            //fill: 'rgb(62, 53, 67)',
            // a Kinetic.Canvas renderer is passed into the drawFunc function
            drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                // layer1/Compound Path
                context.save();
                context.beginPath();

                // layer1/Compound Path/Path
                context.moveTo(54.0, 12.8);
                context.lineTo(34.2, 1.4);
                context.bezierCurveTo(31.2, -0.3, 27.6, -0.3, 24.7, 1.4);
                context.lineTo(4.9, 12.8);
                context.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 14.5, 0.1, 17.7, 0.1, 21.0);
                context.lineTo(0.1, 43.9);
                context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 47.3, 1.9, 50.5, 4.9, 52.1);
                context.lineTo(24.7, 63.6);
                context.bezierCurveTo(27.6, 65.3, 31.2, 65.3, 34.2, 63.6);
                context.lineTo(54.0, 52.1);
                context.bezierCurveTo(56.9, 50.5, 58.7, 47.3, 58.7, 43.9);
                context.lineTo(58.7, 21.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(58.7, 17.7, 56.9, 14.5, 54.0, 12.8);
                context.closePath();

                // layer1/Compound Path/Path
                context.moveTo(32.3, 10.8);
                context.bezierCurveTo(30.7, 10.8, 29.5, 9.5, 29.5, 8.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(29.5, 6.4, 30.7, 5.1, 32.3, 5.1);
                context.bezierCurveTo(33.9, 5.1, 35.1, 6.4, 35.1, 8.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(35.1, 9.5, 33.9, 10.8, 32.3, 10.8);
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(62, 53, 67)";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 0.3;
                context.stroke();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
                context.restore();
            }
        });
        pacMan2 = new Kinetic.Shape({
            x: 15,
            y: 13,
            //fill: 'rgb(62, 53, 67)',
            // a Kinetic.Canvas renderer is passed into the drawFunc function
            drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                // layer1/Compound Path
                context.save();
                context.beginPath();

                // layer1/Compound Path/Path
                context.moveTo(29.1, 36.9);
                context.bezierCurveTo(27.6, 36.0, 26.7, 34.5, 26.7, 32.8);
                context.bezierCurveTo(26.7, 31.2, 27.6, 29.6, 29.1, 28.8);
                context.lineTo(55.2, 13.7);
                context.bezierCurveTo(54.8, 13.4, 54.4, 13.1, 54.0, 12.8);
                context.lineTo(34.2, 1.4);
                context.bezierCurveTo(31.2, -0.3, 27.6, -0.3, 24.7, 1.4);
                context.lineTo(4.9, 12.8);
                context.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 14.5, 0.1, 17.7, 0.1, 21.0);
                context.lineTo(0.1, 43.9);
                context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 47.3, 1.9, 50.5, 4.9, 52.1);
                context.lineTo(24.7, 63.6);
                context.bezierCurveTo(27.6, 65.3, 31.2, 65.3, 34.2, 63.6);
                context.lineTo(54.0, 52.1);
                context.bezierCurveTo(54.2, 52.0, 54.5, 51.8, 54.7, 51.7);
                context.lineTo(29.1, 36.9);
                context.closePath();

                // layer1/Compound Path/Path
                context.moveTo(32.3, 5.1);
                context.bezierCurveTo(33.9, 5.1, 35.1, 6.4, 35.1, 8.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(35.1, 9.5, 33.9, 10.8, 32.3, 10.8);
                context.bezierCurveTo(30.7, 10.8, 29.5, 9.5, 29.5, 8.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(29.5, 6.4, 30.7, 5.1, 32.3, 5.1);
                context.closePath();
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(62, 53, 67)";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 0.3;
                context.stroke();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
                context.restore();
            }
        });
        pacMan3 = new Kinetic.Shape({
            x: 15,
            y: 13,
            //fill: 'rgb(62, 53, 67)',
            // a Kinetic.Canvas renderer is passed into the drawFunc function
            drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                    // layer1/Compound Path
                    context.save();
                    context.beginPath();

                    // layer1/Compound Path/Path
                    context.moveTo(32.0, 36.9);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(28.7, 36.0, 26.7, 34.5, 26.7, 32.8);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(26.7, 31.2, 28.7, 29.6, 32.0, 28.8);
                    context.lineTo(58.7, 22.0);
                    context.lineTo(58.7, 21.0);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(58.7, 17.7, 56.9, 14.5, 54.0, 12.8);
                    context.lineTo(34.2, 1.4);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(31.2, -0.3, 27.6, -0.3, 24.7, 1.4);
                    context.lineTo(4.9, 12.8);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 14.5, 0.1, 17.7, 0.1, 21.0);
                    context.lineTo(0.1, 43.9);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 47.3, 1.9, 50.5, 4.9, 52.1);
                    context.lineTo(24.7, 63.6);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(27.6, 65.3, 31.2, 65.3, 34.2, 63.6);
                    context.lineTo(54.0, 52.1);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(56.9, 50.5, 58.7, 47.3, 58.7, 43.9);
                    context.lineTo(58.7, 43.7);
                    context.lineTo(32.0, 36.9);
                    context.closePath();

                    // layer1/Compound Path/Path
                    context.moveTo(32.3, 5.1);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(33.9, 5.1, 35.1, 6.4, 35.1, 8.0);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(35.1, 9.5, 33.9, 10.8, 32.3, 10.8);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(30.7, 10.8, 29.5, 9.5, 29.5, 8.0);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(29.5, 6.4, 30.7, 5.1, 32.3, 5.1);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fillStyle = "rgb(62, 53, 67)";
                    context.fill();
                    context.lineWidth = 0.3;
                    context.stroke();
                    canvas.fillStroke(this);
                    context.restore();
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here’s how to create a Kinetic.Sprite animation from your “chomping hexes”**

Since you already have the hex + mouth coordinates, you don't even need a pre-created spritesheet.

You can dynamically create your "chomping" spritesheet using an html canvas element.

The method:

- Start with a temporary html canvas element
- Draw all your chomping hexes on that canvas
- Use canvas.toDataURL to convert that canvas into a spritesheet image
- Use that spritesheet normally to run Kinetic.Sprite animations

This is the dynamically created spritesheet created from the html canvas

[image]

The following code shows the canvas on-screen for illustration purposes, but you would create your temporary canvas offscreen.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sEjvx/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    // get a reference to the temp canvas
    // it will be used to dynamically create a spritesheet
    var tempCanvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // define the sprites
    var pac;
    var translateX=0;
    var y1=18;
    var y2=46;
    var ychange=2.5;
    var width=70;
    var height=70;
    var chomping=[];
    var animations={
        stopped:[{x:0,y:0,width:width,height:height}],
        chomp:chomping
    };


    // draw the sprites on the canvas
    // also add the sprite definitions (x,y,width,height) 
    // to the chomping animation
    for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
        drawSprite(translateX,y1,y2);
        translateX+=70;
        y1+=2;
        y2-=2;
        if(i<7){
            chomping.push({x:translateX,y:0,width:width,height:height});
        }
    }


    // convert the sprites on the canvas to a spritesheet image
    // and create a Kinetic.Sprite
    var spritesheet=new Image();
    spritesheet.onload=function(){
        pac=new Kinetic.Sprite({
            x:100,
            y:75,
            image:spritesheet,
            animations:animations,
            framerate:15,
            index:0
        });
        layer.add(pac);

        pac.setAnimation("stopped");
        pac.start();

        layer.draw();
    }
    spritesheet.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();


    // wire up the buttons to start the chomp and stopped animations
    $("#chomp").click(function(){ pac.setAnimation("chomp"); });
    $("#stopped").click(function(){ pac.setAnimation("stopped"); });


    // draw 1 sprite on the canvas
    function drawSprite(translateX,y1,y2){

        // draw hexagon
        context.save();
        context.translate(translateX,0);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(54.0, 12.8);
        context.lineTo(34.2, 1.4);
        context.bezierCurveTo(31.2, -0.3, 27.6, -0.3, 24.7, 1.4);
        context.lineTo(4.9, 12.8);
        context.bezierCurveTo(1.9, 14.5, 0.1, 17.7, 0.1, 21.0);
        context.lineTo(0.1, 43.9);
        context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 47.3, 1.9, 50.5, 4.9, 52.1);
        context.lineTo(24.7, 63.6);
        context.bezierCurveTo(27.6, 65.3, 31.2, 65.3, 34.2, 63.6);
        context.lineTo(54.0, 52.1);
        context.bezierCurveTo(56.9, 50.5, 58.7, 47.3, 58.7, 43.9);
        context.lineTo(58.7, 21.0);
        context.bezierCurveTo(58.7, 17.7, 56.9, 14.5, 54.0, 12.8);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle="blue";
        context.fill();

        // draw eye
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(34,10,3,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle="white";
        context.fill();
        context.strokeStyle="orange";
        context.lineWidth=1.5;
        context.stroke();

        // draw mouth in various stages of chomping
        context.beginPath();                
        context.moveTo(59,y1);
        context.lineTo(25,32);
        context.lineTo(59,y2);
        context.closePath();   
        context.fillStyle="white";             
        context.fill();
        context.restore();

    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="chomp">Chomp</button>
    <button id="stopped">Stop</button>
    <div id="container"></div><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=100></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you start the animation? I used `pac.setAnimation("chomp");` at the end of the code to start the animation but I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'pac.setAnimation')`

Comment: @igaar. Did you get your "undefined" error worked out? Since the pac object is built inside a function, be sure you define it outside the function for global access (var pac; *outside* the function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Kinetic.Animation` with a switch statement to determine which frame to show, something like this:

```
    var group = new Kinetic.Group({
        x:10,
        y:10
    });

    group.add(pacMan1);
    group.add(pacMan2);
    group.add(pacMan3);
    layer.add(group);
    layer.draw();

    pacMan2.hide();
    pacMan3.hide();

    var frameCount = 0;
    var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function (frame) {
        frameCount++;
        var mod = frameCount % 30;
        switch (mod) {
            case 0:
                pacMan1.show();
                pacMan2.hide();
                pacMan3.hide();
                break;
            case 10:
                pacMan1.hide();
                pacMan2.show();
                pacMan3.hide();
                break;
            case 20:
                pacMan1.hide();
                pacMan2.hide();
                pacMan3.show();
                break;
        }
        group.setX(group.getX()+1);
    }, layer);

    anim.start();
```

You can make the frames go by faster by changing the modulo formula and the case numbers.

```
//Faster
var mod = frameCount % 3;
switch (mod) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
}

//Slower
var mod = frameCount % 300;
switch (mod) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 100:
        break;
    case 200:
        break;
}
```

And if you want him to move faster than change the interval that `x` increases by:

```
//Move 5 pixels every frame.
group.setX(group.getX()+5);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/k5LDt/)

It's not a great answer, but it's a start.

---

## The other way

I thought of using the `toImage()` method to turn your `hex` shapes into images, then using that in a `Kinetic.Sprite`

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#toImage

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html

And a tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-sprite-tutorial/

But, I think the problem with that is you need to have an image set up for sprites (something like: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/blob-sprite.png)

Ideally though for your purpose, I think that using a `Kinetic.Sprite` is what you're looking for so if you can set up that sprite based image with your pac man shapes then you'll be set to do a whole ton of things with the **sprite**.